# How to navigate between button(focus) when press Tab in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have set it for <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> for three buttons. The problem is, the button must be focused before pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> ...
I want to use <kbd>TAB</kbd> on keyboard to focus between buttons.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#373737">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,1">
        <Button x:Name="btnPay" FontSize="13" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Margin="0,0,1,0" BorderThickness="0" Width="120" KeyDown="btnPay_KeyDown">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="/Image/receipt.png" Width="40" Height="40" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Foreground="White">Thanh toán (F1)</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnClear" FontSize="13" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Margin="0,0,1,0" BorderThickness="0" Width="120" KeyDown="btnClear_KeyDown">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="/Image/eraser.png" Width="40" Height="40" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Foreground="White">Xóa (F2)</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="btnLogOut" FontSize="13" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Width="120" Margin="0,0,1,1" BorderThickness="0" KeyDown="btnLogOut_KeyDown"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="/Image/password.png" Width="40" Height="40" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Foreground="White">Log Out (F6)</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: By default, "Tab" changes the focused element to the next one. Can you post the XAML with the buttons here? Do you have any other controls on the same layout with the buttons?

Comment: You mean,that pressing F1 does action on 'Play', pressing F2, does action on 'Xóa' and pressing F6 does action on 'Log Out'? is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workaround seems to be an additional problem instead of a solution.
Instead of using the `PreviewKeyDown` events of all the buttons, simply use the one of your Window and decide what to do based on the key pressed.

Window:

```xml
<Window PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
```

Code behind:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool handled = true;
    if (!Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.F1:
                {
                    Play();
                    break;
                }
            // ...
            case Key.F6
                {
                    LogOut();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                handled = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.C:
                {
                    Copy();
                    break;
                }
            case Key.V:
                {
                    Paste();
                    break;
                }
            case Key.Z:
                {
                    Undo();
                    break;
                }
            case Key.Y:
                {
                    Redo();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                handled = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    e.Handled = handled;
}
```

---

Alternatively (this would be en even better solution) you could implement your commands as `ICommand` and use them for input bindings.

```xml
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="S" Command="{StaticResource Save}"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control+Shift" Key="S" Command="{StaticResource SaveAs}"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="Z" Command="{StaticResource Undo}"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="Y" Command="{StaticResource Redo}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{StaticResource Play}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F6" Command="{StaticResource LogOut}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```